# A potencially dangerous Request.FormValue was detected by the client.,

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aynchronousFileUpload control in a userControl. When I am trying to upload a File I have got an error " A potencially......". Usually when I got this error earlier on an aspx page i made validaterequest=false and then it worked ., but now i got this error with a user control any suggestions ......

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.Net 4.0 then this might help: [Change in ValidateRequest in ASP.Net 4.0](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code871-change-in-validaterequest-in-aspnet-40-.aspx)